# How do i create a WPF window in a console app?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an existing project, now i want to create a menu window (using WPF).
I cannot seem to figure out how to add this to my existing project.

How can i implement a "WPF-window" to a console app project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the required references to your console project (PresentationCore.dll, PresentationFrameWork.dll and WindowsBase.dll).

Decorate the entry point method with the `STAThreadAttribute`, to force the the STA thread model for the main thread.

```
class Program
{
  [STAThread]
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    new Window().ShowDialog();
  }
}
```

Consider to create a WPF desktop project and set it as startup project. then reference the console application and run it from the *App.xaml.cs* i.e. use it like a library.